# Problems with entry boxes, can't get entry to equal the correct answer

Tags: tkinter, random

So the goal of this program is to create a random number game. It asks you for the password "Jump" and once that is entered, it opens the game. The game presents you with 4 randomized numbers 0-100, and it asks you to put them in the correct order in the input box. My problem is that everything is working, except when I put the ordered numbers in the entry box, it always is wrong. Do I need to make 4 entry boxes instead? That seems like too much extra work.

```
from Tkinter import *
import random


def getvalue():
    password = ent.get()
    if password == "Jump":
        open_window2()
    else:
        root.destroy()



root = Tk()

lab = Label(root, text='Insert Password', fg="white",bg="blue")
ent = Entry(root, bg='white', fg="blue")
button = Button(root, text='Enter Password', command=getvalue)

ent.focus()

lab.grid(row=0)
ent.grid(row=0, column=1)
button.grid(row=2, column=1)



def open_window2():
    window2 = Tk()

    random_numbers = random.sample(range(100), 4)
    global getvalue2
    getvalue2 = IntVar(sorted(random_numbers))

    def correct_answer():
            user_input = ent2.get()
            print user_input

            """ I can get the lose window to open now, because the program is not
            accepting the correct answer and I can't figure out how to insert it correctly, make 4 input boxes"""
            if user_input == getvalue2:
                window3 = Tk()
                winlab1 = Label(window3, text="You have won! please select play again or exit")
                winbutton1 = Button(window3, text="Play Again", command=open_window2)
                winbutton2= Button(window3, text="Exit", command=window3.quit)

                winlab1.pack()
                winbutton1.pack()
                winbutton2.pack()

                window3.mainloop()

            else:
                window4 = Tk()
                loselab1 = Label(window4, text="You have lost :( please select play again or exit")
                losebutton1 = Button(window4, text="Play Again", command=open_window2)
                losebutton2 = Button(window4, text="Exit", command=window4.quit)
                loselab1.pack()
                losebutton1.pack()
                losebutton2.pack()

                window4.mainloop()



    lab2 = Label(window2, text="Welcome to the number game!", fg="white", bg="blue")
    lab3 = Label(window2, text=random_numbers,fg="white", bg="blue")
    lab4 = Label(window2, text="Please arrange the numbers in ascending order", fg="white", bg="blue")

    """look up how to create extra entry boxes in python"""
    ent2 = Entry(window2)
    global ent2




    button2 = Button(window2, text="submit", command = correct_answer)


    lab2.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
    lab3.grid(row=1, column=1)
    lab4.grid(row=1, column=0)
    ent2.grid(row=2, column=0)
    button2.grid(row=2, column=1)

    root.destroy()




root.mainloop()
```

Comment: One problem is that you should not be creating `Tk()` twice. If you need a second window, create an instance of `Toplevel`

Answer (score 0):

This is not doing what you expect:

```
if user_input == getvalue2:
```

When trying to debug code, the first step is to validate your assumptions about your code. In this case you're assuming `getvalue2` is the value you entered in your widget. If you print it out you will see it's not what you expect.

To get the value from an `IntVar` you must use the `get` method:

```
if user_input == getvalue2.get():
```

Answer (score -2):

1) You are NOT using python3.3 so please remove this tag.

2) The tag random-sample is also not pertinent here.

3) You should have tried to print getvalue2 in correct_answer function and I believe your problem is you didn't declare it as global, or maybe that user_input and getvalue2 have different types so you should convert one of them.